# Culture of knowledge and academic discourse on this board

Tags: discussion

I would like to inform everybody that you are losing me as a contributing member of this community. I cannot stand the hostility against non-engineering (but rather math oriented) approaches to DSP and the general culture of academic discourse that is practised here anymore. I hope those who are contributing to this climate understand who they are. I have always been open for discussion, but I am not open to ridicule and arrogance, as I have faced it here regularly. A simple rule could make things so much easier: If you don't understand it or it's not meant for your but someone with a different perspective, please just ignore it. There is not need to fight it.

Enjoy your time here. I will miss a few contributors who are able of civilised exchange and discussions and who have preserved an open mind. Please keep it like that!

Regards,

Jazz

Comment: Jazz, I'm very sorry to hear that, and I sincerely hope you'll reconsider.

Comment: I have for a long time considered your input in certain areas the best this community can offer, and have read your input with anticipation of in-depth insight. Hopefully you can eventually care less about the disappointments and will come back. It is unfortunate that we cannot always provide fruitful discussion in in-depth subjects that take effort and time to absorb.

Comment: It is a pity that this rather small community seems to be losing a knowledgable member who has contributed in a very significant way over the past years. I'm sure that there are many more people here that have appreciated Jazzmaniac's presence, probably in too silent a way, than there are people who have been critical towards his way of approaching the subject. For the future, I would strongly suggest to keep it friendly and sober, to avoid drama and personal conflicts, and to appreciate more openly any well meant contributions to our site.

Comment: Jazz's activity still remains visible. Let us call the above  "improvisation" and relax with Youn Sun Nah's version of [My Favorite Things](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3q6L8ONqCI)

Answer (score 5):

Jazzmaniac, I'm really sorry to hear that. Thanks for letting us know why you're leaving.  We must do better.

Comment: i ain't down voting this, Peter, but i disagree.  i cannot, for the life of me, see what Jazz is bitching about.

Comment: @Fat32 : Can you point to an example?  I've not been as active here as I have been in the past. I'm working two day jobs and so I have less time to intervene / answer here.

Comment: @Fat32 OK! I'll keep a look out... thanks for weighing in.

Comment: Hi! I would like to remove my comments... I hope you won't mind.

Comment: @Fat32 no worries. It’s a semi-free world. 

Answer (score 4):

I come from the math side too.  My experience on DSP.SE has been fairly pleasant, especially in comparison to the "battles" I've participated in on the comp.dsp newsgroup.  Refutations of DSP dogma, or alternative expressions, seem to be met with unjustifibly severe resistance.  My advice would be to carry on and ignore the trouble makers.  Without outside perspectives any discipline will stagnate into an inbred echo chamber without hope of progressing.  [Sarcasm]After all, everything is already known.[/Sarcasm].

You may want to check out the forum at dsprelated.com.  It moves much slower than DSP.SE, and much much slower than MATH.SE.  I have yet to see any one go into flame war mode over there.  Also, if you have material that you want to present in a cohesive and comprehensive manner you could possibly become a blogger.  It is less formal than writing an academic paper and you have the added benefit of being able to edit your articles after they have been published.  In contrast, it is my experience that IEEE is a hotbed of engineering biased anti-mathematical close mindedness that you are so fed up with.  Not all of them by any means, just a generalization.  Any paper you write for them will be behind a paywall limiting access to any one not in the club.

I upvoted Matt L.'s comment.  I like DSP.SE and losing a contributer is, by definition, a loss.

Answer (score 3):

I only  can offer you a non-answer to your non-question. Let us forget for a moment the mathematician and the engineer sides, and focus on a more lethal discipline: finance. [Alan Greenspan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Greenspan), former Chairman of the US Federal Reserve, is often credited with the quote:

> I guess I should warn you, if I turn out to be particularly clear,
>   you've probably misunderstood what I said.

We can use it as a useful afterthought for all the answers we write. **Please do keep on writing answers I won't understand**. They make me think.

Answer (score 2):

i dunno how i missed this thread (i started another one bringing attention to the mainspace thread that, perhaps, all the fuss was).

i personally cannot see what Jazz is complaining about.  i can't see it at all.